# Sync Windows Live Mail between two computers

Tags: email, sync, nas, windows-live-mail

I have a laptop where I have been using Windows Live Mail as my email application for the last year. Yesterday I got a dell desktop as well and I am desperately trying to set up so my desktop and laptop sync the email between each other.

I'm using Super Flexible Synchronizer to sync the email storage folder to a NAS on my network, so when setting up the desktop naturally I set it up to download all from the NAS. But each time I open Windows Live Mail on the new machine, some emails suddenly come in duplicates, one is read, the other is not.

I have ran through the registry on the new machine and updated an ID i found, in 3 places, one being:
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Live Contacts{blah blah blah}\DBStore\contacts.edb

Still doesn't seem to be enough. Does anyone have any tips or ideas how to sync Windows Live Mail between two computers without duplicates and weird behavior etc.

Answer (score 1):

check out this forum, has a similar question...

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/35474649/synchronize-mail-between.aspx

basically put, it recommends that you use Windows Live Sync to sync your message folder between your two Windows machines.

Comment: thank you for pointing me to that thread studiohack.
unfortunatly i think i have reached further than what is discussed in that thread, and yet some things are not right.

There must be some more registry keys involved...

Comment: sounds like a messy situation...sorry I couldn't be of more help.  good luck!  (and welcome to Super User! :-))